# Dev Environment Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have doubts about how could I create objects, actions and aggregation and test it on development environment. Since facebook needs to scrap my webpage to get the object when i register an action. How could I configure my dev environment?

Answer (score 2):

I've had my network guys poke a hole in the firewall to my dev server and have updated  DNS point my development subdomain (ie dev.domain.tld).